# Left and right align on same line

Tags: html, css

I want to create a `div` that has a header containing two pieces of text. One piece of text will be aligned left and one right. The header will have a gray background that will expand with the text:

```
<div id="expand-box">
   <div id="expand-box-header">
      <span style="float: left;">Top left header</span> 
      <span style="float: right;">Top right header</span>
   </div>
   Lorem ipsum dorem nori seota ostiy
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#expand-box
{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    border: 2px solid #BBB;
    margin: 7px 0 0 0;
}

#expand-box-header
{
    background-color: #BBB;
    margin: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 0 0 3px 2px;
}
```

While this works, the two `spans` float over the `expand-box-header` gray background and the Lorem Ipsum text floats higher than it should.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason your code wasn't working is because floating divs don't affect the size of the surrounding element. The problem you get with **inline-block on your left side float** is that you lose one of your headers as the screen is made smaller. I shrank the screen size on the JSfiddle Mehmet Eren Yener provided and the right header disappears. If your headers are long, and the screen is small - the right header will vanish.

I think the better approach would be to either use a **clearfix** class or to use the **overflow** tag. There's also the **Empty Div Method** - but I'm not really a fan of that one. If you use one of these methods instead the left header will stack on top of the right header when they get too close.

**Here are examples of using Clearfix and Overflow:**

**Clearfix: http://jsfiddle.net/ATP33/**

HTML:

```
 <div id="expand-box">
 <div id="expand-box-header" class="clearfix">
  <span style="float: left;">Top left header</span> 
  <span style="float: right;">Top right header</span>
 </div>
 <div id="expand_box_sub_header">Lorem ipsum dorem nori seota ostiy</div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#expand-box {
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
border: 2px solid #BBB;
margin: 7px 0 0 0;}

#expand-box-header {
background-color: #BBB;
margin: 0;
color: #FFF;
padding: 0 0 3px 2px;}

#expand_box_sub_header { clear: both; }

.clearfix:after { content: "\00A0"; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0;}  
.clearfix{ display: inline-block;}  
html[xmlns] .clearfix { display: block;}  
* html .clearfix{ height: 1%;}  
.clearfix {display: block}
```

**Overflow: http://jsfiddle.net/RL8ta/**

HTML:

```
<div id="expand-box">
<div id="expand-box-header">
  <span style="float: left;">Top left header</span> 
  <span style="float: right;">Top right header</span>
</div>
<div id="expand_box_sub_header">Lorem ipsum dorem nori seota ostiy</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#expand-box {
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
border: 2px solid #BBB;
margin: 7px 0 0 0;}

#expand-box-header {
background-color: #BBB;
margin: 0;
color: #FFF;
padding: 0 0 3px 2px;
overflow: auto;}

#expand_box_sub_header { clear: both; }
```

Comment: Floating is kind of becoming a dying art and is getting more and more discourage in it's use, but if you do use it often this article is useful in understanding float behavior: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 17):

You just need to add `clear:both` `div`

Or

Just create a class [`clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) with property

```
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

---

```
<div id="expand-box-header">
      <span style="float: left;">Top left header</span> 
      <span style="float: right;">Top right header</span>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div> <!-- Here we go --> OR <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XhxCj/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You can do for the left side

```
display:inline-block;
```

Here is the JSFIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/MBwJq/

But first of all, you have inline css code, it is a good practice to not write inline css code at all

clearfix is an old technology, it works but, inline block is to stop using clearfix

Here is the link : [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to the styles for the `#expand-box-header` element. This will automatically clear the floated `span` elements inside it without the need for additional HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

To contain floats use the [micro-clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

So your css for the container will look like this:

```
#expand-box:before, #expand-box:after {
    contents: "";
    display: table;
}
#expand-box:after {
    clear: both;
}
```